# "Enable 'ja_JP.UTF-8' and 'en_US.UTF-8' locales on your system" How do i do this?

Tags: locale, lutris

I am trying to follow the instructions on this site:
https://lutris.net/games/touhou-06-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil/
where it says "Enable 'ja_JP.UTF-8' and 'en_US.UTF-8' locales on your system" it provides instructions how to do it in Arch - how do I do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried to install "locales-all" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose they mean **generate**. On Ubuntu you can do that with a single terminal command:

```
sudo locale-gen ja_JP.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```